# create console application with facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

hi everybody I would like to write a console application that posts message in specialy moment  on facebook , i don't now how to start, please if you have  examples or tutorial or any links that can help me , shared it with me please , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear what is your scenario, but you could try Facebook PowerShell Module http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com.

Comment: i want to build a console application with c# that allow to send post on my wall on facebook

Comment: "ucef", this should be relatively straightforward using either Facebook C# SDK of FacebookPSModule. The tricky bit is getting and securely storing the access token, and this is where FacebookPSModule will help you the most. I recommend one of three approaches:

Comment: (1) Build a C# application using strictly Facebook C# SDK. Store an access token in your user profile as a SecureString.
(2) Build a C# application which uses the System.Management.Automation APIs to invoke your command in PowerShell.
(3) Don't bother with C#, just write a PowerShell script and invoke it using Powershell.exe. This is the easiest approach.

Comment: "Jon"  : thank you very much , i will try to do your advise , thank you